# How to password protect website and keep user logged in, using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, authentication, login-script

I want to make my website password protected. After a user logged in he shouldn't get logged out when closing window or browser. To reach this I'm storing an authentication token as cookie.

This is my code:

```
<?php
// take $_COOKIE['user'] if it exist, else take $_POST['user']
if(isset($_COOKIE['user'])) {
    $user = $_COOKIE['user'];
} else {
    $user = $_POST['user'];
}

// get login data from database
if(isset($user)) {
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT user, password, authentication_token FROM users WHERE user = :user LIMIT 1;');
$stmt->execute(array(':user' => $user));
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($results as $row) {
    $password = $row['password'];
    $authentication_token = $row['authentication_token'];
}
}

// set passwort and authentication token at first visit and login
if($password == "" && isset($_POST['user'], $_POST['password'])) {
$unique_authentication_token = hash('sha256', uniqid(rand().time(), true));
$statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET password = :password, authentication_token = :authentication_token WHERE user = :user");
$statement->execute(array(':user' => $_POST['user'], ':password' => hash('sha256', $_POST['password']), ':authentication_token' => $unique_authentication_token));
setcookie("user", $_POST['user'], time()+(10*365*24*60*60));
setcookie("authentication_token", $unique_authentication_token, time()+(10*365*24*60*60));
unset($_POST);
header('location: https://www.example.com');
exit;
}

// show login form if no data or wrong data
if(!isset($_COOKIE['user']) || !isset($_COOKIE['authentication_token']) || $_COOKIE['authentication_token'] != $authentication_token) {
    $showLogin = 1;
}

// login
if(isset($_POST['user'], $_POST['password']) && hash('sha256', $_POST['password']) == $password) {
    setcookie("user", $_POST['user'], time()+(10*365*24*60*60));
    setcookie("authentication_token", $authentication_token, time()+(10*365*24*60*60));
    unset($_POST);
    header('location: https://www.example.com');
    exit;
}

// login form
if($showLogin == 1) {
echo "
<form action=\"\" method=\"post\">
<select name=\"user\">
<option>George</option>
<option>Harald</option>
<option>Peter</option>
</select>
<input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" placeholder=\"Password\">
</form>
";
exit;
}
?>
```

Is it the right way I'm doing it? Can you see any vulnerables? What can I do better?

Comment: it is better to use md5 password or store as jwt token

Comment: @Sakezzz Really? I thought `md5` isn't recommended. Isn't `sha256` even better? What is `jwt token`?

Comment: Why not use $_SESSION after login?

Comment: @David it is better than what you now

Comment: @RonnieOosting What line do you mean?

Comment: @David Jwt token is string encrypted with private key. You can read more here https://jwt.io/. I used that for my users microservice;

Comment: @Sakezzz So I should use salted hash for password hashing instead?

Comment: I have not debugged your code but I see a lot of $_COOKIE. You mentioned 'login' before, and for that you should use $_SESSION. So basically what it does: After login -> Set $_SESSION -> redirect to dashboard/or any page where it should be redirected to. From there on the $_SESSION data will stay alive, until the session gets destroyed. Examples and documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: @David yes for sure. It lets to not bruteforce you password if database was stolen

Comment: @David what about code I would recommend to read this post https://medium.com/@DonnaInsolita/the-evolution-of-php-developer-4d3c2fdfa1ae :)

Comment: @Sakezzz Okay, I guess I'll use `JSON Web Tokens`.

Comment: @RonnieOosting I don't really understand but I'll read about it and get back with my updated code.

Comment: @Sakezzz I'll update my code an get back with it. `Salted hash` or `JSON Web Tokens`?

Comment: JSON Web Tokens:) Salted hash is passed, jwt is more secure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177633/discussion-between-sakezzz-and-david).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review (and this thus too broad / opinion based). It could probably be adjusted to be on topic for [the code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Comments by Sakezz are very confused.

Yes using a salted hash is hugely better than an unsalted one, but SHA is a much more secure hash than MD5. But php comes with a `password_hash()` function (and [a whole chapter in the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.password.php)) which does all the clever stuff for you, allows use of better hashes and simplifies migration to new hash mechanisms.

You are using an authentication token which can be revoked and is effectively random. That's good - although a user can't be logged into more than one device at a time. Do you provide a mechanism for users to logout? (This is important).

You are using parameter binding for your queries, again good, but an even better approach for security would be using a stored procedure with privilege desperation - and the account you connect with should have no read/write access to the table.

The coding style is ok, but unless you have a reason for sticking with it, I suggest psr-1 & 2

Comment: Interesting that there's 2 downvotes and no other comments.